# error while copying a 2d array to another array

Tags: python, arrays

I am beginner in Python. I am trying to copy a 2d array(a) to another array(b) but getting an error 'int object doesn't support assignment'. I understand there may be other functions available to copy but here i am trying to understand python. Can someone please point what is wrong with below code.

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
b = []
for row in a:
    newrow = [0] * len(row)
    b += newrow


for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        b[i][j] = a[i][j]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `b` is a 1 dimensional list because you are extending it instead of appending. Change the line

```
b += newrow
```

to

```
b.append(newrow)
```

That being said, you could easily copy one array into another like this:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
b = a[:]
```

or using the built-in `copy` module:

```
import copy
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
b = copy.copy(a)
```

Comment: Thanks @Selcuk. It worked with append. i am using Sedgewick's book to learn python. Strange the book misses on append in 2D array explanation.